# Is it possible to change a Pokémon’s tera-type?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

When it comes to the competitive scene, the implementation of the terastal types changes a lot when building teams. I’ve mentally come up with some ideas, but trying to farm for a specific tera-type for a specific Pokémon would take a while.

Is it possible to change the Pokémon’s tera-type after it’s been caught?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can change the tera type using Tera Shards. These are dropped by Pokemon defeated in Tera Raids, or occasionally found on the ground. You need to bring 50 of them to a [particular NPC in a restaurant in Medali](https://dotesports.com/pokemon/news/what-are-tera-shards-and-what-do-they-do-in-pokemon-scarlet-and-violet) to change a Pokemon's Tera Type.